# Reformat an inputbox value stored as integer to use in SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I am trying to use two separate inputboxes to return values to use in my file name, the formatting of the file name has to be very specific because it is an upload file.

I need the year and the month in the file name but the month is in the file name twice, in one instance it is in the file name as MM or 06 and one instance it is in the file name as M or 6.

I have code that returns my entered year and month which are currently 2022 and 6.
The second Month in the file name is formatted correctly as 6 but I need the first Month in the file name to be formatted as 06 which I know is the NumberFormat "0#" but I can't figure out how to get it in that format.

```vb
Dim Year As Integer
Dim Month As Integer

Year = InputBox("Enter the Year", "Year", "YYYY")
Month = InputBox("Enter the Month", "Month", "M")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Year & Month & "-janusus;import-actual-" & Year & Month & "-R.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

I tried the below code.

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Year & Format(Month, "0#") & "-janusus;import-actual-" & Year & Month & "-R.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Code I am trying to get to work in response to findwindow:

```vb
Dim Year As Integer
Dim Month
Dim Month1
Dim Month2

Year = InputBox("Enter the Year", "Year", "YYYY")
Month = InputBox("Enter the Month", "Month", "M")
Month1 = WorksheetFunction.Text(Month), "00")
Month2 = WorksheetFunction.Text(Month), "00")
```

Comment: `format(InputBox("Enter the Month", "Month", "M"),mm`?

Comment: I can't get this to work, I don't know if you can just reformat around the InputBox like that

Comment: Declare `month` as string then you can do `month="0"&InputBox("Enter the Month", "Month", "M")`.

Comment: I don't need every month to have a zero in front of it though, plus I need the single digit month as well. If it is December I don't need it to be 012 I just need 12. Also, I need the 6 and the 06 in the file name. I'm trying to figure out a way to re-format it after the input box for that reason, because I will need the 6 and the 06 for the file name

Comment: `Month = WorksheetFunction.Text(InputBox("Enter the Month", "Month", "M"), "00")`

Comment: Ok, so that worked, however, if I go that route I will have to have two input boxes for the month which isn't a huge deal but I'm trying to avoid confusion for the end user. Is there a way to reformat it somehow like the code I just posted at the bottom of my original question then I can use the Month1 and Month2 in my save name? I just can't get this code to work but it seems like I should be able to I'm just not super savvy with coding.

Comment: Or you can think about modifying the above?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out, I appreciate all your help! I had a parentheses  in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of findwindow I have come to the conclusion below, works perfectly. I appreciate all your help findwindow!

```
Dim Year As Integer
Dim Month1
Dim Month2

Year = InputBox("Enter the Year", "Year", "YYYY")
Month1 = InputBox("Enter the Month", "Month", "M")
Month2 = WorksheetFunction.Text(Month1, "00")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Year & Month2 & "-janusus;import-actual-" & Year & Month1 & "-R.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```